# How can I use Constants?

Tags: java, constants

I have a homework assignment that requires me to use constants. I'm not sure which part of the code snippet below could use a constant.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PP2_6
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    float mileage, kilometer;

    System.out.print("Enter the Mileage: ");
    mileage = myScan.nextFloat();

    kilometer = mileage * 1.60935F;

    System.out.println("The mileage in kilometers is : " + kilometer);
}
}
```

Can you assist with how I can use a constant in this code?

Comment: You should probably delete this question as it isn't very helpful to other users, but here is a hint.. It is not good form to have an arbitrary number in code, it should be assigned to a variable first with a good descriptive name so you know what it is.

Comment: The magic number of 1.60935F should be a constant. And you could also have your text beginning with "The mileage in..." as a constant, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 kilometer = mileage * 1.60935F;
```

declare that number as static final field (constant) before method main:

```
public class PP2_6 {
    public static final float CONSTANT = 1.60935F;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    kilometer = mileage * CONSTANT;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very important to use good naming standard. In stead of CONSTANT  you should use CONVERSION_FACTOR and also, constant should be private, if scope of it is only this class.